# How to use the default input Query Selector in my VSTS's widget configuration?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm developing an extension for vsts (visualstudio.com), this extension will show some values based on WorkItem's tags.

To do this I want that the user select in the widget's configuration which query he want to show WorkItems info.

I want to use the default input to select a query in this configuration, like this example:
[image: VSTS-default query selector]

How can I do that? It's possible to use this query selector in my widget's configuration page?

Comment: I guess you don't want to simply show the results of the query, right? As Marina said, there already is widget for that. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Flex you are correct, I want to do more things with the query result. I just focus the question to what I need, that is put a input to select a query in the widget's configuration. But I improved my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

You can show the queries in the [TreeView control](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/controls/tree) in configuration page. To get the queries, you can use [getQueries()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_2#method_getQueries) method of **TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient**.

There are many samples that you can refer to (e.g. **build-inspector**, **widgets**)

[vsts-extension-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)

Comment: There is any example using TreeView in configuration page? Because they only show how to use out of the configuration page. I try to use, but have no sucess

Comment: @thur you can refer to build-inspector sample to learn how to use TreeView control.

Comment: @thur The simple sample: [Use the treeview control](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/ui-controls/treeviewo)

Comment: I try to use it, but if I try to load the nodes after the creation of the TreeView, it doesn't show anything... Because I need to load the nodes after the api's response

Comment: @thur What's your code? You can do it in then function. Check this code: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/widgets/templates/scripts/Widget-for-sample-configuration.js